# calculate moving multiplication average in r

Tags: r

For a data `a= c(1,2,3,4)` how do I calculate the square root of moving multiplication average? The result should be `b=c(1.41,2.44,3.46)`. Is there a builtin function in R like there is for moving average `filter(a, rep(1/2,2))`. If I use `sqrt(cumprod(a))` I am quite close to getting the desired result. What should I change here?

Comment: You could use `sqrt(a[-1]*a[-length(a)])` for this particular example, or work on the log scale:  `exp(filter(log(a), rep(1/2,2)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
sqrt(RcppRoll::roll_prod(a, 2))
```